# services.mysql Additional property website is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

version: '3.8'

volumes:
datafiles:

services:
mysql:
image: mysql:latest
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
container_name: mysql_ecommerce
environment:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345
- MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3308:3306
volumes:
- datafiles:/var/lib/mysql
restart: always

```
website:
 container_name: web_ecommerce
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
 enviroment:
  - MYSQL_DBHOST=mysql
  - MYSQL_DBPORT=3306
  - MYSQL_DBUSER=root
  - MYSQL_DBPASS=12345
  - MYSQL_DBNAME=
 ports:
  - 8082:80
  - 8083:443
 depends_on:
  - mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check your docker-compose file and ensure it follows the correct indentation.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql:
  website:
```